# Theory question about stochastic block matrix $P = \begin{pmatrix}P_1 & 0 \\ R & Q \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$P =  \begin{pmatrix}P_1 & 0 \\ R & Q \end{pmatrix}$ is a stochastic $n \times n$ matrix. With $P_1$ being  $r \times r$ and $R \neq 0$.

Show that:

a) $P_1$ is an $r \times r$ stochastic matrix and $Q$ has at least one row sum less than 1.

b) the left eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 1 must have the form $p^\top = (p_1^\top 0)$ where $p^\top$ is an r-vector.

Alright so I have no clue how to solve this. This is what I have come up with this far.

Since P is a stochastic matrix we can reorder the rows columns, so for example if 
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0.5 & 0.5
\end{pmatrix}$$
We can change place on the first and second column and then change place of the first and second row aswel to get
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0.5 & 0.5\\
0.5 & 0 & 0.5
\end{pmatrix} = \left(\begin{array}{c|c c}
 1 &0 & 0\\
 \hline
 0 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
 0.5 & 0 & 0.5
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c|c}
 P_1 & 0 \\ \hline R & Q
\end{array}\right)$$
For b) if we if we raise $P^n$ we get $\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
 I & 0 \\ \hline \star & 0
\end{array}\right)$ when $n$ gets large.

Where $\star = (I+Q+Q^2+... +Q^{n+1})R$. Then perhaps the first row will somehow, magically, be the r-vector $p^\top$.

A solution would be great, a source for theory that will help me tackle this problem and others like it would be even better :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways to attack this -- it depends quite a bit on how much you know (/want to know) about linear algebra vs stochastics.  Part 1 comes down to basic blocked multiplication, i.e. with $\mathbf 1_n :=  \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 1_r  \\  \mathbf 1_{n-r} \end{bmatrix}$ consider $\mathbf 1  = P \mathbf 1$ but write this out blocked, can you say anything about components of  $R\mathbf 1_r$ vs $Q\mathbf 1_{n-r}$.  Depending on what you know... you can immediately infer that $Q$'s perron root $\lt 1$ but $P$ has an eigenvalue 1, so that means the eigenpair is associated with $P_1$ ...

Comment: How do I interpret $1_n := \left[\begin{array}{c} 1_r \\ 1_{n-r} \end{array}\right]$? Is $1_r$ a r-vector consisting of 1 in every slot?    

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: yes $\mathbf 1_n$ is a vector with n ones in it and I bipartitioned in order to facilitate a blocked multiplication argument.  **Note** your current problem statement is technically invalid-- it needs to say somewhere that there is a single class in $Q$ or that via $R$ all states in $Q$ communicate with those in $P_1$ -- as currently stated $Q$ could technically be reducible into say 2 classes one transient and one that is (positive) recurrent

Comment: If $P$ is a $n \times n$ and $P_1$ is $r \times r$ should not R be $(n-r) \times (n-r)$ and Q $r \times r$ then $R1_r$ and $Q1_{n-r}$ are undefined, right?

Comment: No. If those dimensions are true for R, then P doesn’t exist as you’ve written it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ is given and the question asks you about the properties of $P_1$ and $Q$. You cannot permute the rows and columns of $P$ at will, although you may permute the first $r$ rows/columns and the last $n-r$ rows/columns separately, so that the original block structure remains intact.

Part (a) is easy. If $R\ne0$, then some entry $r_{ik}$ is positive. Therefore
$$
1=\sum_jr_{ij}+\sum_lq_{il}\ge r_{ik}+\sum_lq_{il}>\sum_lq_{il}.
$$
Part (b) as it stands is not true. Here is a counterexample:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c|cc}1&0&0\\ \hline\frac12&\frac12&0\\ 0&0&1\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}0&0&1\end{array}\right].
$$
However, the problem statement is true if *every* row of $R$ is nonzero. In this case, every row sum of $Q$ is less than $1$. Hence the induced maximum norm $\|Q\|_\infty$ is less than $1$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}Q=0$.

Now suppose $v^TP=v^T$. Then $v^TP^2=(v^TP)P=v^TP$ and in turn, $v^TP^n=v^T$ for every $n\ge1$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}v^TP^n$ exists and is equal to $v^T$. However, if we partition $v^T$ as $(x^T,y^T)$, then $v^TP^n$ is in the form of $(\ast,y^TQ^n)$. It follows that
$$
v^T=\lim_{n\to\infty}v^TP^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\ast,y^TQ^n)=(\ast,\,y^T\lim_{n\to\infty}Q^n)=(\ast,0).
$$